# Сохранить данные при удаления приложения из "Меню последних запущенных"

Tags: android

Как-то можно отловить момент удаления приложения из меню? onDestroy при этом не вызывается.

Comment: Что за данные, почему нельзя сохранять в `onPause()`? Такой колбэк есть у сервиса [`onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service#ontaskremoved), но стоит ли из-за этого добавлять сервис в приложение.

Comment: Понятно. Видимо придется сохранятся в onPause().. что не желательно (такая логика приложения).

Comment: что такое для вас удаление приложения из меню ?

Comment: чем вас не устраивает метод onStop()?

Comment: @SweetDev Это когда удаляешь из списка "последних запущенных”